# R how to match regex "_a (b)"

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

I am crazy about this question. In R language regex, how to match a pattern "_a (b)"? a and b both stand for a word, there is a space in front of (.

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("dum_drop (words)", "apple")
# I want to match and remove the part "_drop (words)"
str_remove(x, pattern = "[_drop (words)]")
# result
# [1] "um_drop (words)" "aple"
```

I think the regex expression about the pattern "_drop (words)" needs some work.

Comment: You should show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Correct match:

```
x <- c("dum_drop (words)", "apple")
str_remove(x, pattern = "_drop [(]words[)]")
# result
# [1] "dum"   "apple"
```